# Custom control that detects first child which will be rendered as a html input field

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to develop a custom control that automatically detects the first child control which will be rendered as an input-tag. I'm doing this because I want to know if I should render my associated title as a label or a span element in the HTML (a bit like the `asp:Label` works when an `AssociatedControlID` is given).

I found that most of the `HtmlControls` that will be rendered as an input field derives from the base class `HtmlInputControl`. But I didn't find any class alike for the controls in the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace.

So my question is, am I stuck with digging up the protected property "TagKey" with reflection like this:

```
var property = control.GetType()
    .GetProperty("TagKey", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var tag = (HtmlTextWriterTag)property.GetValue(control, null);
```

or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check if a control implements IPostBackDataHandler interface? This will give you the ability to select controls which provide value back to the server. Though they may not necessarily be rendered as `input`. For example DropDownList implements that interface but is rendered as `select`...

Comment: Good point, though as you said that interface dont guarantee that the control will be rendered as an input. Even though the select element would be valid in the "for" attribute other controls liek the CheckBoxList would reference a non existing id.